# How can i change all button color?

Tags: python, tkinter

Soo this is my code

```
for i in range(22):
    burtas.append(
        Button(
            logs,
            text=burti[i],
            fg="black",
            bg="light grey",
            width=3,
            font="Arial 20 bold",
        )
    )
    burtas[i].place(x=1 + 60 * (i % 9), y=530 + 55 * (i // 9))
    burtas[i].bind("<Button-1>", burtsKlik)
```

How do i change all the button color at the same time?

Comment: Easy way would be to say `root.tk_setPalette('red')` but this will set everything to red.
`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change them all in a single invocation, but you can just loop over all of them and [configure the elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#setting-options):

```
burtas = []

for i in range(22):
    burta = Button(
        logs,
        text=burti[i],
        fg="black",
        bg="light grey",
        width=3,
        font="Arial 20 bold",
    )
    burta.place(x=1 + 60 * (i % 9), y=530 + 55 * (i // 9))
    burta.bind("<Button-1>", burtsKlik)
    burtas.append(burta)

# ...

for burta in burtas:
    burta["fg"] = "red"
    burta["bg"] = "blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the tkinter button, making a version that remembers instances of the class and can modify them all at a later point in time

```py
class MyButton(tk.Button):
    objects = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.objects.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def set_config(cls, **kwargs):
        for obj in cls.objects:
            obj.config(**kwargs)

    def destroy(self):
        self.__class__.objects.remove(self)
        super().destroy()
```

Then in your code, you could use the `set_config` class method to modify all created instances of `MyButton`, like so

```py
for i in range(22):
    burtas.append(
        MyButton(
            logs,
            text=burti[i],
            fg="black",
            bg="light grey",
            width=3,
            font="Arial 20 bold",
        )
    )
    burtas[i].place(x=1 + 60 * (i % 9), y=530 + 55 * (i // 9))
    burtas[i].bind("<Button-1>", burtsKlik)

MyButton.set_config(fg='red', bg='green')
```